# Jama SVD for calculating the Pseudoinverse

Tags: algorithm, svd, jama

I'm unsure if I should post this on Stack overflow or Mathematics but I thought this question fits into algorithm studies so here I am.

I've written an algorithm to calculate the pseudoinverse of a given matrix.
I've done this using a naïve way using the definition A<sup>+</sup> = (A<sup>*</sup>A)<sup>-1</sup>A <sup>*</sup>.

I've read more into this and found that a common way to calculate it more stable and efficiëntly is calculating the SVD of A first. (I do this using the Jama package)

However. The naïve method proves to be faster (in time) on small matrices.

A quick question.
I believe the SVD method has a better complexity than the naïve way. But can you give me an idea on how big the matrix has to be so the SVD method is actually faster in terms of time?

Comment: Maybe unrelated to your computation related question, but the matrix A\*A may not be invertible if A is not full column rank. Also, SVD will be much more numerically stable, forming A\*A is undesirable most of the time, unless A has some special structure that can be exploited. **Edit**: I just saw your computing this on small matrices. If you're dealing only with small matrices your method might be fine.

Comment: The matrix A may have an undefined size and is always a vandermonde matrix where each row is different so it is full column rank. The reason I want the pseudoinverse is because I want to use it in the least squares method.

Comment: IIRC, vandermode matrices are quite numerically unstable to work with. Maybe you should be avoiding forming them in the first place?